# How to unregister two vertx consumers and returns an rxjava completable?

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x

I need a small help with Rxjava . currently I have two hash maps . Each hash map contains vertex message consumers against a subscription key. I want to return a completable object only if I am able to unregister both vertex message consumers. How can I achieve it .

I can post the code i am working on.

@Override
public Completable deregisterKeyEvents(String subscriptionId) {

```
MessageConsumer<JsonObject> messageConsumer = consumerMap.get(subscriptionId);
MessageConsumer<JsonObject> subscriptionConsumer = subscriptionConsumerMap.get(subscriptionId);


if( subscriptionConsumer != null) {
    subscriptionConsumerMap.remove(subscriptionId);
    subscriptionConsumer.unregister( res-> {
        
        if(res.succeeded()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Subscription channel consumer deregistered successfully!");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to de-register Subscription channel consumer");
        }
        
    });
}

if (messageConsumer != null) {
    
    consumerMap.remove(subscriptionId);
    
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
        
        messageConsumer.unregister(res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                emitter.onComplete();
            } else {
                emitter.onError(res.cause());
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    LOGGER.warn("There was no consumer registered!");
    return Completable.create(emitter -> emitter.onError(new KvNoSuchElementException("Subscription '" + subscriptionId + "' not found")));
}
```

}

I want to rewrite the above code in such a way

subscriptionConsumer.unregister() & messageConsumer.unregister() is successful then return a completable

The MessageConsumer class is from vert.x libary io.vertx.core.eventbus.MessageConsumer.
appreciate if you can help
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to add [Vert.x RxJava2](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java2/) to your dependencies, you could do this with [`toCompletable`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/reactivex/CompletableHelper.html#toCompletable-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
@Override
public Completable deregisterKeyEvents(String subscriptionId) {

    MessageConsumer<JsonObject> messageConsumer = consumerMap.get(subscriptionId);
    MessageConsumer<JsonObject> subscriptionConsumer = subscriptionConsumerMap.get(subscriptionId);
    
    Completable c1;
    if( subscriptionConsumer != null) {
        subscriptionConsumerMap.remove(subscriptionId);
        c1 = CompletableHelper.toCompletable(handler -> subscriptionConsumer.unregister(handler))
            .doOnSuccess(() -> LOGGER.debug("Subscription channel consumer deregistered successfully!"))
            .doOnError(t-> LOGGER.error("Unable to de-register Subscription channel consumer", t));
    } else {
        c1 = Completable.complete();
    }
    
    Completable c2;
    if (messageConsumer != null) {
        consumerMap.remove(subscriptionId);
        c2 = CompletableHelper.toCompletable(handler -> messageConsumer.unregister(handler));
    } else {
        LOGGER.warn("There was no consumer registered!");
        c2 = Completable.error(new KvNoSuchElementException("Subscription '" + subscriptionId + "' not found"));

    }

    return c1.concatWith(c2);
}
```

Note that this is a bit different than your original code because:

- the `messageConsumer` unregistration happens only after the unregistration of `subscriptionConsumer`,
- the `messageConsumer` unregistration happens only if unregistration of `subscriptionConsumer` was successful.

You can use a different method of [`Completable`](https://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) if that's not the behavior you want.